# PHP How to transform an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, transform

I have an array which get from POST data

```
Array
(
    [date_from] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/10/2015
            ...
        )

    [date_to] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01/11/2015
            ...
        )

    [price_eur] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            ...
        )

    [price_usd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            ...
        )

)
```

And I want to transform it to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['date_from']   => 01/10/2015
            ['date_to']     => 01/11/2015
            ['price_eur']   => 8
            ['price_usd']   => 9
        )

    ...
)
```

How to transform this php associative array?

Comment: Did you researched a bit ? Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just freehanded this.  let me know how it goes

```
foreach ($original as $key => $arr){
    foreach ($arr as $x => $y){
        $new[$x][$key] = $y
    }
}
```